# Definability lemma and comprehension in Kunen

Tags: set-theory, forcing

I’m reading the chapter on Forcing of Kunen’s Set Theory, where he discusses the implications of the Definability Lemma on the Comprehension Axiom:

[image]

where the referenced equation is:

[image]

And the preceding discussion regarding the problem with comprehension is:

> […] say $\varphi(x,y)$ is a formula and $\sigma \in M^\mathbb{P}$. Why should the set $S=\{n\in\omega: (\varphi(n,\sigma_G))^{M[G]}\}$ be in $M[G]$?

As I understand it, the Definability Lemma implies that for some formula $\psi$ in the language of set theory $\{\in\}$ we have

$$\{(p,\mathbb{P},\le,\mathbb{1},\vartheta_1,\vartheta_2): (\mathbb{P},\le,\mathbb{1})\ \text{is a forcing poset}\wedge p\in\mathbb{P}\wedge \vartheta_1,\vartheta_2\in M^\mathbb{P} \wedge p \Vdash_{\mathbb{P},M}\varphi(\vartheta_1,\vartheta_2)\}
$$
$$=\{x\in M:\psi(x)\}$$

so to see $\tau\in M$ it would suffice to show $\tau$ belongs to the first set. Is this correct? How would I go about proving it?

Comment: What is $\mathcal{D}^-(M)$? Is it the set of all definable elements of $M$?

Comment: @HanulJeon sorry, I forgot to clarify, it's the set of definable (without parameters) subsets of M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set given in the lemma is *not* a set of names or a name itself, therefore you can't prove $\tau$ is an element of your first set. However, Your reasoning which says the first set is of the form $\{x\in M : \psi(x)\}$ is correct, so we can use it to specify names from a set of names.

For example, you can easily check that the set of names $\{(\check{n},p) : n<\omega\land p\in P\}$ is a member of $M$. By comprehension on $M$, the set
$$\{(\check{n},p) : n<\omega\land p\in P\land \psi(p,\check{n})\}$$
is an element of $M$, where $\psi(p,\check{n})$ is a formula which is equivalent to
$$p\in P\land \check{n}\in M^P\land p\Vdash_{P,M} \phi(\check{n},\sigma).$$

In fact, the form of $\psi$ is not exactly same to that of the formula in the theorem. However we know that $P$ is a forcing poset of $M$ so we can just join a formula that asserts "$P$ is a forcing poset" at a side of $\psi$ and we can make it to have that form.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm not sure I see where exactly you're using the lemma. I follow your usage of comprehension on $M$ to form that set, which by your later comment can be shown to be of the form $\{(\check{n},p): \alpha(p,P,\le,1,\check{n},\sigma)\}$ where $\alpha$ is as in the statement of the theorem, but what does this tell us?

Comment: @Reveillark The existence of $\psi$ is guaranteed by the lemma. As you may noticed, $\Vdash$ is defined externally (since it mentions $M$ and generic ultrafilters not in $M$) so we should ask we can internalize the forcing relation. The definability lemma says the answer is yes.

Comment: Ah, I think I see it now, and I also understand your usage of "a formula which is equivalnet to", you need the lemma to ensure that such a formula exists, once you have such a thing, you can go ahead and apply comprehension. Is this correct?

Comment: @Reveillark Yes, it is what I intended.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you very much! :)